# How to create Own Access Token validated by Auth0 in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, auth0

I have an existing system and want to utilize `Auth0`(still considering).

**Context:**

I have my own login screen, which is quite dynamic(white labeled) per client. So I dont want to use Auth0 login screen.

I have my own user and tenant database, so dont want to use Auth0 user database for now.

So the idea is to validate the user credentials after login on my backend and create access token to return to client side.

I want that access token to be validated by Auth0.

**Questions:**

1) Probably most important question. Should go with Auth0 or just stick with native jwt's

2) Is there a way I can create a valid access token in my backend which can be validated by Auth0.

**Stack:**

I am using vue.js as my front-end SPA.

I am using .net core as my backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Probably most important question. Should go with Auth0 or just stick with native jwt's

That is determined by whether you want to enable the online identity provider's features like Single Sign-On . If not , just keep using the current one since you don't need the Auth0 user database .

> Is there a way I can create a valid access token in my backend which can be validated by Auth0.

Since your scenario is collect username and password in front-end application , and pass to backend .net application to validate credential and create token . You can [implement the Resource Owner Password Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant) in Auth0 to create access token for accessing resource which protected by Auth0, but as document shows :

> You should use this flow only if the following apply:
>
> - The application is absolutely trusted with the user's credentials. For Single-Page Apps and Native/Mobile Apps, we recommend using web flows instead.
> - Using a redirect-based flow is not possible. If this is not the case and redirects are possible in your application, you should use the Authorization Code Flow instead.

So that it's **not recommended** in your scenario . If you need the features like SSO and want to use Auth0 , it is recommended to directly use Auth0 in vue application to manage your users and roles :

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login

After login with Auth0  , you can map the user to local database user for specific management if needed .

Another way is using [Client Credential flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials) . For this scenario, typical authentication schemes like username + password or social logins don't make sense. Instead, M2M apps use the Client Credentials Flow , your backend app will authenticates and authorizes the app rather than a user. It's not suitable if you want to acquire access token for specific user to access protected resource .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am busy looking at machine-to-machine. Hereby my backend would make a call to Auth0 to get a access token.

On the note of Auth0 Login. My existing login screen is whitelabeled by client. So 10 different client would have different login screens.

Comment: if using [client-credentials flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials) , there is not user context in token .But yes , you can use that flow using client's credential .

Comment: One last question. You could also maybe update the answer with it. What would be the best approach if one wants to use own Login screens and Own user database.

Comment: As i said , resource owner flow need username/password which may lead to security problem . The client credentials flow allows an application to get a token without the context of the user , but it uses app's identity . The problem is do you need the user related information when acquiring access token , for example , do you need make the api only access by specific user ? If no , then client credentials flow is ok .